# Creating snapshot and export in new Azure SDK .NET - Azure.ResourceManager

Tags: c#, .net, azure, sdk, azure-sdk-.net

Because old Azure SDK for .NET is deprecated, I'm trying to migrate it to new version. I've been stucked with finding substitions for old methods and properties in new SDK. We do a snapshot of existing database and export to Storage Account.

Snippet of old approach:

```
var sp = new ServicePrincipalLoginInformation()
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret
            };
var credentials = new AzureCredentials(sp, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var azureClient = Authenticate(credentials).WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

var sqlServer = await azureClient.SqlServers.GetByIdAsync(db.SourceServerId);

var serverDbs = await sqlServer.Databases.ListAsync();
var snapshotDb = serverDbs.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == snapshotDbName);
if(snapshotDb is not null)
   return;

snapshotDb = await azureClient.SqlServers.Databases
                        .Define(snapshotDbName)
                        .WithExistingSqlServer(sqlServer)
                        .WithSourceDatabase(sourceDatabaseId)
                        .WithMode(CreateMode.Copy)
                        .CreateAsync(cancellationToken);
.
.
.
var storageAccount = azureClient.StorageAccounts.GetByIdAsync(storageId);
await snapshotDb.ExportTo(storageAccount, storageContainer, outputFileName)
                            .WithSqlAdministratorLoginAndPassword(user, password)
                            .ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
```

According to documentation, I was able to get this:

```
var sp = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var azureClient = new ArmClient(sp, subscriptionId);

var ri = new ResourceIdentifier(NOT SURE WHAT SHOULD BE HERE);
var resGroup = azure.GetResourceGroupResource(ri);
var sqlServerResponse = await resGroup.GetSqlServers().GetAsync(sourceServerId);
var sqlServer = sqlServers.Value;

var serverDBs = sqlServer.GetSqlDatabases();
var snapshotDB = serverDBs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Data.Name == db.SnapshotDbName);
```

What are substitution commands, which handle creating snapshot and exporting to Storage Account base on parameters used in deprecated sample? Or do I miss some Package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a [general guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/resource-management?tabs=PowerShell) for using our latest version of .NET SDK against resource management.
Regarding your issue, you can refer to code below

```cs
var resourceGroup = _client.GetDefaultSubscription().GetResourceGroup(resourceGroupName).Value;
            var sqlServer = resourceGroup.GetSqlServer("mySqlServerName").Value;
            var sqlDB = sqlServer.GetSqlDatabase("myDbName").Value;
            var exportResult= sqlDB.Export(Azure.WaitUntil.Completed, new Azure.ResourceManager.Sql.Models.DatabaseExportDefinition("storageKeyType", "storageKey", new Uri("storageUri"), "adminLogin", "adminLoginPWD")).Value;
```

The `_client` here is ArmClient object,
your code `var ri = new ResourceIdentifier(NOT SURE WHAT SHOULD BE HERE);` is not necessary, may I know why do you want to create a resource identifier here?

Please make sure you are using 1.1.0 version of Azure SDK for SQL libirary in .NET

We are open to any feedback regarding our new SDK, feel free to let us know your thoughts on our new SDK in this [survey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/GBKP57G)